# Создать папку во внутренней памяти. В корне

Tags: java, android, io

Необходимо создать папку именно в корне.. чтобы она была общедоступна. Затем скопировать в нее файл из папки приложения.
Делаю так:

```
File f = new File("путь");
f.mkdirs();
```

Но не знаю какой путь задать.

Comment: Если речь про android, то тут нельзя просто создавать папку в любом месте. Без особых разрешений можно создать папку (или файл) по пути getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(). Но всё находящееся в этой папке доступно только вашему приложению и никакому больше. Так же можно получить доступ для чтения(записи) в общедоступные папки. Для этого в манифесте должны быть прописаны соответствующие разрешения. А, например, путь к общедоступной папке с Изображениями можно получить так: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Создать папку **во внутренней памяти**. В корне
>
> Необходимо создать папку именно в корне.. **чтобы она была общедоступна**

Вот эти два предложения противоречат друг другу.

Внутреняя память (*internal storage*) – это область памяти, которая выделяется для каждого приложения и доступ к ней имеет только приложение, ассоциированное с ней. У каждого приложения своя *внутреняя память*.

Чтобы папка была общедоступна, ее можно создать во внешней памяти (*external storage*). Здесь стоит заметить, что *external storage* -- это не обязательно SD-карта, это вполне может быть внутренняя память телефона.

Получить путь до корня внешней памяти можно с помощью метода:

```
File getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

класса `Environment`.

Тут следует заметить, что внешняя память доступна не всегда, поэтому перед ее использованием необходимо проверить ее состояние с помощью метода:

```
String getExternalStorageState().
```

класса `Environment`.

Подробнее про сохранение данных можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).